# Problems deploying with Capistrano and Perforce after changing workspace

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano, perforce

we have been uising capistrano to roll out changes for some time (it was set up by a previous coder). as IT have decided to remove his workspace from perforce ive created a new one in my name and figured it would just work, but it seems to be rolling back on [deploy:update_code].

ive chekced the usual username / password errors, and with any of these incorrect the error is 
Perforce password (P4PASSWD) invalid or unset.
or
p4client is incorrect or unset

so im quite confident it isnt that.

any ideas? ill paste the error message in ommiting any details!  thanks a lot

failed: "sh -c 'p4 -p p4SERVER:1666 -u P4Username -P p4Password -c P4Workspace sync -f @298781 && cp -rf `p4 -p p4SERVER:1666 -u P4Username -P p4Password -c P4Workspace client -o | grep ^Root | cut -f2` /home/ubuntu/clan/releases/20110905145323 && (echo 298781 > /home/ubuntu/clan/releases/20110905145323/REVISION)'" on ipaddressofserver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this problem. the issue was that when creating the workspace the "host" was specified as being my local machine, removing this optional param allowed it to deploy correctly